# What is difference between BI Answers and BI Publishers?

Tags: obiee

I have recently used BI Answers for analytics reporting in OBIEE, however I have heard about BI publisher as well. I am new to reporting hence kindly bear with me for my basic queries around this. May I know the difference between these 2.
Thanking you in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIP = pixel perfect reporting. Static, but you can control - as the definiton implies - every pixel. So it's geared towards static output like printing, financial report etc. https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/bi-publisher.html

Answers is one of the on-the-fly, self-service/expert-level construction and dynmic anayltical tools of the Oracle Analytics platform. End-users and experts can use it and it's fully dynamic for changes in scope, point of view, security, etc etc.